# Trying to convert kml to geojson and getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with geotools

Tags: geojson, kml, geotools

I am trying to convert a kml to geojson with geotools 20.5 and i am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. 
The file i am trying to convert can be converted on other frameworks correctly but on geotools i had this error.
I am using geotools 20.5 and java 8. 
Can someone help me?

My code:

```
try {
            reader = new FileInputStream("file.kml");
            PullParser parser = new PullParser(new KMLConfiguration(), reader,
                    SimpleFeature.class);

            FeatureJSON fjson = new FeatureJSON();
            FileWriter tmp = new FileWriter("file.geojson");
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(tmp);
            ArrayList<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
            SimpleFeature simpleFeature = (SimpleFeature) parser.parse();
            while (simpleFeature != null) {
                features.add(simpleFeature);
                simpleFeature = (SimpleFeature) parser.parse();
            }
            SimpleFeatureCollection fc = DataUtilities.collection(features);
            fjson.writeFeatureCollection(fc, writer);
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The Error:

```
nov 05, 2019 10:34:58 AM org.geotools.feature.DefaultFeatureCollection add
ADVERTÊNCIA: Feature Collection contains a heterogeneous mix of features
nov 05, 2019 10:34:58 AM org.geotools.feature.DefaultFeatureCollection add
ADVERTÊNCIA: Feature Collection contains a heterogeneous mix of features
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
    at org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureImpl.getAttribute(SimpleFeatureImpl.java:179)
    at org.geotools.geojson.feature.FeatureJSON$FeatureEncoder.toJSONString(FeatureJSON.java:603)
    at org.geotools.geojson.feature.FeatureJSON$FeatureCollectionEncoder.writeJSONString(FeatureJSON.java:663)
    at org.json.simple.JSONValue.writeJSONString(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.JSONObject.writeJSONString(Unknown Source)
    at org.geotools.geojson.GeoJSONUtil.encode(GeoJSONUtil.java:276)
    at org.geotools.geojson.feature.FeatureJSON.writeFeatureCollection(FeatureJSON.java:311)
    at br.gov.serpro.dnit.sgpd.managedbean.util.KmlUtil.main(KmlUtil.java:65)
```

my file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="FILEP" id="FILEP">
    <SimpleField name="descriptio" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="timestamp" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="begin" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="end" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="altitudeMo" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="tessellate" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="extrude" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="visibility" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="drawOrder" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="icon" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Vertice" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="N" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="E" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Name_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="descript_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="timestam_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="begin_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="end_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="altitude_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="tessella_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="extrude_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="visibili_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="drawOrde_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="icon_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Vertice_2" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="N_2" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="E_2" type="float"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>FILEP</name>
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#FILEP">
        <SimpleData name="tessellate">-1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="extrude">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="visibility">-1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Vertice">99.000000000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="N">8183148.594999999700000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="E">745077.081499999970000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="tessella_2">-1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="extrude_2">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="visibili_2">-1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Vertice_2">191.000000000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="N_2">8210502.734000000200000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="E_2">736058.699299999980000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Polygon><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-54.7917363536269,-16.1742594701822 -54.7895814786832,-16.1734821399515 -54.7895800001009,-16.1734859993162 -54.7917363536269,-16.1742594701822</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Lote 1.1</name>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#FILEP">
        <SimpleData name="tessellate">-1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="extrude">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="visibility">-1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Vertice">99.000000000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="N">8183148.594999999700000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="E">745077.081499999970000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Polygon><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-54.7029330000828,-16.418827003687 -54.7050349995717,-16.4206240055189 -54.7066909997516,-16.4186669998587 -54.7097899998139,-16.4152840050737 -54.711284000096,-16.4137840012491 -54.7155259996671,-16.4091309999561 -54.7159569996756,-16.4085860056906 -54.7164260000864,-16.4078180037582 -54.7167560002403,-16.4070890068105 -54.7170000000898,-16.4063140036972 -54.71716799977,-16.4053310064691 -54.7171859996123,-16.4043040003729 -54.7142569996992,-16.3849039995536 -54.714219000075,-16.3831400057174 -54.7143560002966,-16.3824300040174 -54.7146070001402,-16.3817500050653 -54.71507299986,-16.3809680075699 -54.7166420002163,-16.3791200011844 -54.7294440001037,-16.3653540023959 -54.7303290003941,-16.3640530055761 -54.735744,-16.354199003456 -54.7362829999685,-16.3533360017841 -54.7370200002648,-16.3524110008306 -54.7434739998639,-16.345426002351 -54.7443780000589,-16.3442420020091 -54.7452380003799,-16.3428140000797 -54.7458840000393,-16.3414490038868 -54.7474169999057,-16.3376550078664 -54.7585620001911,-16.3081250034321 -54.7593819998013,-16.3057130032081 -54.7608040000599,-16.3021880024424 -54.7683409995231,-16.2821870054936 -54.7697669996656,-16.2788180019092 -54.7760910000798,-16.2658120055877 -54.777188000237,-16.2633620029799 -54.779149000021,-16.2595250017392 -54.7795659996092,-16.2585190004681 -54.7799890001377,-16.2568250072184 -54.7834109998234,-16.2351520022125 -54.7835120001112,-16.2338919997834 -54.7834749995869,-16.2329900000154 -54.7833099997024,-16.2319180067533 -54.7808520003183,-16.2222720071977 -54.7798469999294,-16.2187010033988 -54.7796859996364,-16.2177010019671 -54.7796989996353,-16.2169960072611 -54.7812380003992,-16.2104790041366 -54.7817089997954,-16.207916001936 -54.7855579997548,-16.1919780052685 -54.7859999995245,-16.1905900033254 -54.7921979998959,-16.1744260003105 -54.7917363536269,-16.1742594701822 -54.7895800001009,-16.1734859993162 -54.7895814786832,-16.1734821399515 -54.7895699999615,-16.1734779992206 -54.783170000137,-16.1901650015924 -54.7826590000205,-16.191985000899 -54.7795909999637,-16.2046900069761 -54.7788599999872,-16.2078260046823 -54.7784839999407,-16.2099620009427 -54.7769399996402,-16.2164780005795 -54.7768780002604,-16.2177400055293 -54.7770959995268,-16.2192370022489 -54.7780970002354,-16.2227990005203 -54.7805239996236,-16.2323020024959 -54.7807069998312,-16.2337339998721 -54.7806530003063,-16.2346350009768 -54.7796580001503,-16.2410680053836 -54.7772139998481,-16.2564260020182 -54.7769069997749,-16.2576530053378 -54.7759169995376,-16.2597970009449 -54.7743950003939,-16.2627320054949 -54.7735329996322,-16.2646990079405 -54.7672499999347,-16.277618002331 -54.7658179997151,-16.2809599995937 -54.758144000203,-16.3013210010215 -54.7571670001441,-16.303667006542 -54.7559009997175,-16.3072620028212 -54.7447920002151,-16.3366950055191 -54.7432859997169,-16.3404240038616 -54.742708999522,-16.3416370066335 -54.7420549997786,-16.3427210051719 -54.7412709997459,-16.3437460057347 -54.7349009995287,-16.3506340073675 -54.7339589999036,-16.3518160028645 -54.733309000119,-16.3528480065132 -54.7279190004019,-16.3626599997099 -54.7272100000687,-16.3637130028044 -54.7145129997873,-16.3773530021394 -54.7128520003898,-16.3793080023477 -54.7123450001003,-16.3800669997029 -54.7120129994799,-16.3807140075095 -54.7116419998058,-16.3817360064993 -54.7114329998469,-16.3828000045365 -54.7113769994761,-16.3836630077601 -54.7114639999648,-16.385185999841 -54.7143010000668,-16.4039050008073 -54.7143900001083,-16.4047160012712 -54.714286000192,-16.4056130011044 -54.7139429998633,-16.4065520004201 -54.713322000095,-16.4074510052629 -54.7045899997694,-16.4168690051387 -54.7029330000828,-16.418827003687</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Lote 1.2</name>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#FILEP">
        <SimpleData name="tessella_2">-1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="extrude_2">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="visibili_2">-1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Vertice_2">191.000000000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="N_2">8210502.734000000200000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="E_2">736058.699299999980000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Polygon><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-54.7917363536269,-16.1742594701822 -54.7922089999336,-16.1744290055315 -54.7938209996617,-16.1701900053446 -54.7940470003131,-16.1693140075326 -54.7941340003908,-16.1685960014647 -54.7941199996626,-16.1676940072815 -54.7939350003224,-16.1666630066868 -54.7925110002514,-16.1622500063043 -54.7925040003942,-16.1617810034919 -54.7925990000144,-16.1614320074617 -54.7930269994926,-16.1608480052903 -54.7937059998702,-16.1604610002311 -54.7973809996163,-16.1589220019762 -54.7982700001723,-16.158481002857 -54.8022849996873,-16.1558349992484 -54.8035560001701,-16.1550730046464 -54.8332190002705,-16.1352210001957 -54.8363979998726,-16.1329980068579 -54.8380640000272,-16.1319970063641 -54.8464969996475,-16.1263600076539 -54.8484350002558,-16.1254090021821 -54.8492340003468,-16.1249420055654 -54.8570829999307,-16.1197110008907 -54.8580929996083,-16.1189100034289 -54.8589340002961,-16.1179430043422 -54.85972399999,-16.1165230014504 -54.8662159998127,-16.1006880035181 -54.8666899998138,-16.0992420076199 -54.867387999647,-16.0974970010668 -54.8689899996549,-16.0938380071676 -54.8717319996195,-16.0869240066956 -54.873719999521,-16.0822280066624 -54.8747899998844,-16.079422005047 -54.8753869997046,-16.0774110066516 -54.8757060002378,-16.0759370074174 -54.8759,-16.0741260051309 -54.8759159998384,-16.0723200021113 -54.8757810003674,-16.0707000042784 -54.8755039994578,-16.0690960071385 -54.8750910001775,-16.0675200054315 -54.8731150001449,-16.0622580058197 -54.8730270000878,-16.0611799999066 -54.8731909998119,-16.0602930048823 -54.8733900000749,-16.0597860010721 -54.873757000174,-16.0591580055416 -54.8814580000444,-16.0483999998769 -54.8821729998501,-16.0472170015211 -54.8827150000317,-16.0457300025457 -54.8842359996216,-16.0385130012909 -54.8845860000154,-16.0375840038308 -54.8885070001226,-16.0318600014585 -54.8889900001126,-16.0313100078803 -54.8899300003221,-16.0307230027508 -54.8978859999417,-16.0264379999814 -54.8991510001851,-16.0255870077106 -54.9026539997779,-16.0223329993815 -54.9040479997293,-16.0211300014127 -54.9116059999491,-16.0140509997868 -54.9147340001337,-16.0110170020562 -54.9153340002629,-16.0103260001817 -54.9158880003838,-16.0093850036588 -54.9161809995596,-16.0085290061173 -54.9177380003519,-16.0010910002096 -54.9181470001722,-16.0000830001473 -54.9187279997894,-15.9991700001243 -54.92523499991,-15.992183000068 -54.9270239998885,-15.9898680010555 -54.9284549998288,-15.9882140031562 -54.9329190002499,-15.9826310042419 -54.9338029999333,-15.9813890003924 -54.9353190001611,-15.9794860026873 -54.9370679997235,-15.9775199990725 -54.9414250003811,-15.9720110062388 -54.9419960001669,-15.970875001874 -54.9422859996544,-15.9696560010253 -54.9430359996107,-15.9693570053339 -54.9436990002224,-15.9692150069177 -54.9461180000472,-15.9692400070883 -54.9461319997248,-15.9689280011463 -54.9446259998902,-15.9688420064682 -54.9441319996873,-15.96868100092 -54.9435749996239,-15.9683400021668 -54.9430159999523,-15.9678280049986 -54.9429949998482,-15.967699003753 -54.9431099998527,-15.9675130056331 -54.9430280001149,-15.9670160032897 -54.9427140002326,-15.9664270069603 -54.9424819996609,-15.966486004333 -54.9422089999057,-15.966202002875 -54.9421579997093,-15.9629520022339 -54.9423149994915,-15.9626270066505 -54.942588999661,-15.9623849995062 -54.9429989996229,-15.9622560060469 -54.943641000118,-15.9622500052059 -54.9436739997101,-15.9595390016343 -54.9426650000815,-15.9595640042039 -54.9417190001236,-15.9597900018166 -54.9408989995735,-15.9602180041673 -54.9400980002731,-15.9609700064163 -54.9396289999933,-15.9617480063748 -54.9393789995464,-15.9625820068765 -54.9393249998396,-15.9632910075316 -54.9393810001848,-15.9649400067881 -54.9390790002001,-15.9649940024099 -54.9385820000376,-15.9649260038096 -54.9373350001855,-15.9642440069293 -54.937143000049,-15.9645160038586 -54.9382380003222,-15.9653269996369 -54.9383609999695,-15.9655400047613 -54.9385350002078,-15.9662660066783 -54.9394800002914,-15.9676930069366 -54.9394820003079,-15.9694900043374 -54.9392689997784,-15.9701800071804 -54.938962999916,-15.9706970026846 -54.9347969996021,-15.9759280032372 -54.9330899998383,-15.9778430069674 -54.9315250003736,-15.9798089996532 -54.9306500002115,-15.9810389997913 -54.926256999649,-15.9865330033011 -54.9247730003493,-15.9882520078848 -54.9231989996791,-15.9903090003603 -54.9198549998185,-15.993961007981 -54.9171739998167,-15.9967350012632 -54.9165219995898,-15.997497006295 -54.9159489997194,-15.9983230042391 -54.9153659999944,-15.9994540072115 -54.9150069997949,-16.0004720001409 -54.9134840002342,-16.007782005397 -54.9132590002368,-16.0084260045417 -54.9129520000097,-16.0088780014516 -54.909653000019,-16.0121070070789 -54.9020910003464,-16.0191900042551 -54.9007810002864,-16.0203160004128 -54.89727700017,-16.0235679996742 -54.8963449995521,-16.0241689999587 -54.8881849999514,-16.0285670064647 -54.8871169995592,-16.0292930051009 -54.8861510000528,-16.0303910038224 -54.8821339996596,-16.0362700022902 -54.8818149994902,-16.0369230074527 -54.8815420001116,-16.037747004198 -54.8800190003427,-16.0449770035663 -54.8796360003403,-16.0460650055883 -54.879100999669,-16.0469310002938 -54.8714400002761,-16.0576320029156 -54.8709329997891,-16.0584710067496 -54.8705179999957,-16.0594770060334 -54.8703050001203,-16.0603560022655 -54.8702259996582,-16.0610740077299 -54.8702410001438,-16.0619770010153 -54.870345000364,-16.0626920023187 -54.8706159995148,-16.063652005651 -54.8724080001386,-16.0683060045964 -54.8727719999225,-16.0697070012208 -54.873010999579,-16.071134004702 -54.8731199996537,-16.072575003067 -54.8730979999925,-16.0740200025374 -54.8729550000146,-16.0753989993192 -54.8726819996942,-16.0766960017518 -54.8721819997228,-16.0784169998499 -54.8710159999692,-16.0814700047165 -54.8692869995768,-16.0855260031509 -54.8663839996935,-16.0928380032664 -54.8648179995951,-16.0964090072594 -54.8640360000779,-16.0983650067959 -54.863602999897,-16.0997060030276 -54.857052000037,-16.1156579997902 -54.8566540002702,-16.1163640040636 -54.856183000342,-16.1169240013657 -54.8554629995512,-16.1174990048953 -54.8482029996459,-16.1223420035287 -54.8471339997851,-16.1230080035295 -54.8450510002112,-16.1240360023776 -54.8365010003375,-16.1297450005548 -54.8349329995611,-16.1306830007023 -54.831599999663,-16.1330080016845 -54.8020919996387,-16.1527580010607 -54.8005209996253,-16.1537150011526 -54.7972820003853,-16.1558800050084 -54.7963080003236,-16.1564160056591 -54.7922299995441,-16.1581400046299 -54.7911179997587,-16.1588620057383 -54.7904979996332,-16.159536001425 -54.7900399999569,-16.1603210036527 -54.7897649997954,-16.1611829996721 -54.7896849997155,-16.1620810077988 -54.7898909999428,-16.1633270059747 -54.7912170002848,-16.1673310000546 -54.7913320002567,-16.1679950049167 -54.7913269997345,-16.1685360055641 -54.7910729997534,-16.1695890027316 -54.7895814786832,-16.1734821399515 -54.7917363536269,-16.1742594701822</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

my pom:

```
<properties>
        <geotools.version>20.5</geotools.version>
    </properties>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-xsd-core</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-xsd-kml</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to attach some parts manually to geojson. 
this way worked for me:

```
private static StringWriter kmlToGeojson(InputStream input) throws XMLStreamException, IOException, SAXException {
        PullParser parser = new PullParser(new KMLConfiguration(), input, SimpleFeature.class);
        FeatureJSON fjson = new FeatureJSON();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        ArrayList<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleFeature simpleFeature = (SimpleFeature) parser.parse();
        sw.append("{    \"type\": \"FeatureCollection\",    \"features\": [");
        while (simpleFeature != null) {
            SimpleFeatureType featureType = simpleFeature.getFeatureType();
            fjson.setFeatureType(featureType);
            fjson.writeFeature(simpleFeature, sw);
            simpleFeature = (SimpleFeature) parser.parse();
            if (simpleFeature != null) {
                sw.append(",");
            }
        }
        sw.append("]}");
        sw.close();
        return sw;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the error message "`Feature Collection contains a heterogeneous mix of features`". The GeoJSON writer creates the schema based on the first feature and assumes that the rest are the same.

you need to use [`setFeatureType`](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/geojson/feature/FeatureJSON.html#setFeatureType-org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType-) to tell it what the "real" schema looks like.